# How to hide images of apk?

Tags: android, apk

The base function of my application is showing images. I can extract the contents of an apk package on a PC. It is easy to see all assets in the package - among others the contained images. I would like to hide those images. They should only become visible at run-time on the device an user installed the package on.

Is there is any way to solve this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the images encrypted or somehow scrambled.

Since the key has to be in the APK, it will always be possible to crack by determined attacker, so don't bother with anything extra strong. Simple cipher with key in code is enough to stop the usual overly curious user.

Comment: I thought of not to get into encrypt and decrypt process but yet to do now.

Comment: ur answer is useless, of course we need to encrypt it. the question is how? any good frameworks or tutorials?

Answer (score 2):

Well there is a way around for this stuff.

1. Create an database with Image table in sql-light.
2. Store All the Images in BLOB field.
3. Present or database when user intsall the APK
4. Read all the Images from DB and present on UI.
5. When user un-install the app; Remove the DB as well.

I know this is big but this is secure way to secure your images and make APK.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply but here image load is heavy to work with db and have to carry each image.

Comment: Do not store the images that are part of your AP UI but store those that you are managing for SHOW... E.g do not save Banner Image, Header Image, Footer image, menu images etc but store images that presented to user when he run the app. E.g In case of ANIMAL info App store images of Animal In DB and do not save other images

Comment: @arshadkr: Sqlite is very fast. However the disadvantage is that it needs to be extracted from the apk, while the images can usually be read directly from the archive.

Comment: If its so victim can easily fetches images from assets.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to generate a unique identifier for the user and then downloading the images from a remote server after passing that unique id. The remote server reads the unique id and encrypt the files based on that unique id plus some other string that you may put in your code.